# Using a specify block to code a clock to output hold time?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

You can set a module path delay in a specify block as follows (in this case, the `clock` to `q` delay in a DFF):

```
specify
  specparam tPLHc = 4:6:9, tPHLc = 5:8:11;
  (clock *> q) = (tPLHc, tPHLc);
endspecify
```

In other words, the minimum delay for a 0->1 transition on `q` is 4 time units, and so on. However, this only gives the delays for a new valid output on `q`, and doesn't specify how long the previous `q` output holds after a clock edge (or the stability window over which the new `q` is valid). Assume, for example, that `q` remains valid for 2 time units after a clock rising edge, and takes on the new value after 4 time units.

Is there some way to specify the output hold time, or does this have to be manually coded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That information is built into the setup/hold requirements of the next stage. Realize that the min/max delays are statistical thresholds on a slope, and the true output slope depends in the input slopes. And those slopes depend on resistance/capacitance networks that you cannot normally get without analog analysis. So the hold times have to be pessimistic enough to give you practical worse case senarios.

Comment: Ok, I think I see where you're coming from, thanks. Basically, if you're a tool doing SDF back-annotation, or you're manually setting delay values, then (a) you set the `(clock *> q)` delay to the _intrinsic_ cell `tpHL/tpLH`, ignoring everything else, and (b) you roll the source cell `tOH`, _and_ the destination-specific load delay, _and_ the destination `tSU/tH`, _and_ the src/dst clock skew, into a single combined stability window relative to the _source_ clock (because there's only one clock in the Verilog source). Does that make sense?